# Integrating Adobe Flex applications with HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html, flash, apache-flex, adobe

How can I get my Adobe Flex applications to seamlessly integrate with HTML pages?

That is, I want Flex to:

1. Not take up the entire page (make it any size page element I want).
2. Talk back to the JavaScript on the page (further linking the Flash application with the HTML page).

Thanks! ♥

Comment: My guess is you have not used Google or the search function in the top right corner of this page... correct?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Not take up the entire page (make it any size page element I
>      want).

One way might be to specify the height and width of an [HTML Embed tag](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/embeddedobjects/_EMBED.html):

> 1. Talk back to the JavaScript on the page (further linking the Flash
>      application with the HTML page).

Use [ExternalInterface](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/External+Interface).